# Charity For Anscestors

Tags: belief, karma, daana

Is there any merit of making charity on the name of ancestors to us?

We often do charity on our name that for sure directly gives us merit.

But Is there any merit to us if we do charity on the name of our ancestors?

Comment: Why you want to block your chances of attaining moksha by focusing on merits?

Comment: Asking just for information in Hinduism :)

Comment: IMO You will get merits of doing service(sewa) of your anscestors, same as we do sewa of our ancestors when they were alive. After their life journey ends then this is how we can still do sewa of our ancestors. Sewa means to provide benefits(physical/mental/spiritual etc) to someone with our action. And we can do that even after their death. Charity merit will be given to ancestors and sewa merit will be given to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am slightly confused as regards what exactly you are asking but the charities that are made during the Shraddha rituals are the ones made in the names of the ancestors. And, such charities are considered as highly meritorious.

> As fire exists in all [pieces of] wood [in an invisible form but is
>   manifested] by friction, **so virtue is, forsooth, visible by gifts
>   made at a S'raddha.** (356)
>
> To make gifts at a S'raddha is undoubtedly equal to the understanding
>   of the meaning of all the scriptures, bathing at the sacred places and
>   the fruit of all the scriptures. (357)
>
> **Atri Smriti verses.**

And some more verses from the same Smriti:

> Of all gifts, **that made at a S'raddha is superior**.
>
> **The gift [made] at a S'raddha is [the instrument of] purification,
>   when sin equal to [the Mount] Meru [in height] is committed.**

Comment: Not only during shradhha.. I wanted to ask .. Eg. Many people donate for construction of mandirs (as we can see on many bricks .. In the memories of Late Mr./Mrs.XYZ) or Food donation (bhandara) in the memories of late.. Or someone construct a cancer hospital in the memory of their ancestor who died due to cancer.. Does that give merit to a person who done a charity or merit goes to person for/in the memories of  whom charity is done ?

Comment: Ok, no i think the merit goes to you not the ancestors. Because i read in some scripture the bad/good deeds we do do not affect our ancestors who are dead. So, going by that logic you will get the merit it seems @CSharper

Comment: If ancestors are not getting any merit or not getting any relief then what is use of donating in the memories of ancestors?

Comment: @CSharper They surely are getting some relief but you are also getting merit. The merit is obtained by giving them relief only.